# SVN ANT "Add" Task with "force" Option Gives "is already under version control" build error

Tags: xml, svn, ant, svnant

Using ANT and SVNANT, I want to check in a working directory that has a mix of svn-controlled files and new files and sub-directories. According to my understanding of the SVN ANT ["add" task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#add), using the "force" flag as I have below should do something similar to `svn add --force *`

Basically, I'm having the same issue described in [this issue](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1426) at the CollabNet site.

Here's my xml config:

```
<target name="add-new-files-to-test-repo" depends="check-out-projects">
    <svn username="${svn.test.username}" password="${svn.test.password}" svnkit="true" javahl="false">
        <add
            force="true" > 
            <fileset dir="${svn.testdir}"/>
        </add>
    </svn>      
    <echo message="Adding new files to SVN"/>
</target>
```

Gives the response:

```
svn: 'D:\Workspaces\TreXProjects\Build\testdir\New Text Document.txt' is already under version control
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this working right after I wrote this, by re-reading the documentation I linked. As the part about using the "force" flag with the `<add>` task indicates:

> (applies only when dir attribute is set).

So my fixed code reads:

```
<target name="add-new-files-to-test-repo" depends="check-out-projects">
    <svn username="${svn.test.username}" password="${svn.test.password}" svnkit="true" javahl="false">
        <add force="true" dir="${svn.testdir}" >
        </add>
    </svn>      
    <echo message="Adding new files to SVN"/>
</target>
```

Of course, this means you can't use the `<fileset>` task's "include" attribute to skim 
for specific files, as the author of the issue linked in my question wanted to do. My work-around here is to check out the working directory from 
SVN, copy only the files I want into that working directory using a filtered 
 and then  that directory.